# EmberJS and weird IDE (text editor) compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ide, sublimetext2

I'm sure many people have noticed that EmberJS has a weird behaviour when code is written in IDE. That is because the HTML code is inside the  tag, where IDE's expect JS, not HTML.

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <!--<h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>-->

      {{outlet}}
 </script>
```

**Sublime**: The above h2 tag looks like it isn't commented at all. If you use shortcut for commenting, then it adds // comments which are not doing anything, they slashes just get rendered into browser.

**Brackets**: No HTML tags are recognised, they appear as pure text

**TextWrangler**: Only the closing tags are highlighted as HTML tags

These are the three I tried, nothing seems workable. Is anyone having any other IDE or knows how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inside a handlebars template definition did you try using handlebars comment syntax?

Use comment in templates with `{{! }}` or `{{!-- --}}`.

### Example

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="entry">
    {{! This comment will not be in the output }}
    <!-- This comment will be in the output -->
  </div>
</script>
```

### Update

If you use Sublime Text, than you could use a plugin for the correct comment formatting like: https://github.com/nrw/sublime-text-handlebars

Hope it helps.

Comment: It still looks weird, as if it was uncommented in the IDE. I tried in Sublime. My original questions was about the IDE, not how to comment out. It is not helpful at all if none of the comments are shown as commented text in the IDE.

Comment: @Ska, if you use Sublime, why not try something like this: https://github.com/nrw/sublime-text-handlebars?

Comment: :) Well why don't you add that to your answer so I can mark it as answered. Thanks.